# Obtener valor de un metodo que regresa un valor con ajax, alguna idea de como hacer funcionar el codigo?

Tags: javascript, html, c#, ajax

Tengo un boton que al darle click me lleva a una funcion en la que quiero utilizar un ajax

```
<td><button name="btn-delete" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="Sing()" >Singleton</button></td>
```

Mi funcion es:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function Sing() {
           
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "About.aspx/SingletonCall",
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert(response);

                    },
                    error: function (xmlhttprequest, textstatus, errorthrown) {
                        alert(errorthrown);
                        alert(textstatus);
                    }
                });
        }
       
    </script>
```

esta funcion manda a llamar un metodo que regresa un valor

```
  public partial class About : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
        public static string SingletonCall()
        {
            string x;
            Singleton mySingleton = Singleton.Instance;
            x = mySingleton.DoSomething();
            return x;
        }
    }
```

Bueno lo que yo quiero hacer es publicar en el alert de la funcion Sing la x que regresa el SingletonCall, pero lo que en realidad me esta regresando es parte de codigo como esto : " <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC " -//W3C..." algo bastante largo pero sin importncia y que no contiene el valor de la x que busco. Debe haber un error con mi ajax, alguien tiene una idea de que puede ser?

Comment: en tu funcion de error solo dejala así  `error: function(data)` y dentro de esa función imprime `$("body").html(data.ResponseText);` para ver el error en caso de que no esté enviando nada.... y haces los mismo en el `success` pero con `$("body").html(response.ResponseText);`.... Adjuntas imagen de lo que te muestre, solo así te podremos ayudar, de otra forma es difícil saber cuál es tu problema exactamente

Comment: Hola, hice lo que me dijiste y ahora en el modal me muestra un [object]

Comment: no lo imprimas en el modal, hazlo en el body para que puedas ver bien formateada y legible lo que te devuelve